# How to create a bushy rose plant when leaves only appear on the top?

Tags: roses

Background: I bought a rose stem with root, planted it, and it began growing.  The growth produced a plant that had a thick stem (diameter of a magic marker) with leaves only on the top.  Like a 3 foot long tree.  I really want it to spread out, and be short and bushy.

Guidelines indicate I should cut off no more than 1/3.  If I cut off 1/3, I will be cutting *all* foliage from the plant.  Should I attempt this anyway in hopes new growth starts with a split at a lower point if I want to achieve a wide rose bush with many branches?

Comment: The correct time to prune a rose it in winter when it is dormant, and it won't have any foliage then in any case. The important thing is that you leave some *buds* on the stem which will grow into new branches next year.

Comment: Do you know the variety of rose? How long have you had it? With that kind of growth habit, it might be a climber and not a bush, but adding a photo to your question might help with a good answer